# Prove that if a number can be written in the form $n(n+1) , n+2$ can never be a factor of the number .

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I actually did not find this in any book , what actually happened is i was proving an equation and I came across the question I posted .If anyone can help me that would be great.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Are you excluding $n=0$?

Comment: Yes taking only natural numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $n+2$ is a factor of $n(n+1)$. Since $n+2$ and $n+1$ are coprime, $n+2$ divides $n$ by [Euclid's Lemma](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_Lemma). For positive $n$ this is impossible since the absolute value of the divisor cannot exceed the original number (in this case, $|n+2|\le |n|$).

However, if one considers the nonpositive integers (which I am clearly not accustomed to), a few more solutions crop up. We can still use Euclid's Lemma to conclude $n+2$ divides $n$.

We write:

$$k(n+2) = n \leadsto n=-\frac {2k}{k-1}=-\left(2+\frac2{k-1}\right)$$

so $k-1$ must be a divisor of $2$. This gives $k=3,2,0,-1$, which corresponds to the solutions $n = -3,-4,0,-1$. Checking that our original expression is zero at $0,-1$, no more solutions can be found.

Comment: Can i use what i just asked as a theorem ?

Comment: It is better to include a short proof since this result is not exactly well-known, albeit trivial.   Also my answer is incomplete; as J.W.Tanner pointed out, $n$ could be zero.

Comment: but it is obvious that 0 is excluded from the proof

Comment: It is not; rather it is $-2$ that is excluded.

Comment: Oooooh Thanks i was looking at my own question in the wrong way !

Comment: Since you're considering $n < 0$, note that for $n \in \{-3,-4\}$ we have $(n+2) \mid n(n+1)$.

Comment: Uh-oh. Time for a rewrite.

Answer (score 4):

Begin by noting that $ n+2 $ shares no common factors with $ n+1 $.  So we would need $ n + 2 $ to be a factor of $ n $, which is absurd (for positive $n$).

Comment: Look up the definition of coprime and try applying it directly.  The proof is only a short hop away from the definition!

Comment: Can i use what i just asked as a theorem ?

Comment: i got it why n+1 and n+2 are coprimes after commenting lol